# How to send images in MMS in Android programmatically

Tags: android

I want to make Android apps for sending images using MMS. Here is the problem:

```
final ConnectivityManager connMgr = 
         (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
final int result = 
         connMgr.startUsingNetworkFeature( ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE, 
                                           Phone.FEATURE_ENABLE_MMS);
```

Phone.FEATURE_ENABLE_MMS feature is not available.

Comment: Are You Sending MMS Using In-Built Functionality?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 2):

Just use enableMMS instead of the above constant. If you donwload the complete Android code you can get the above data.

Answer (score 0):

you can used this.
[Android:How to send a voice as mms attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441725/androidhow-to-send-a-voice-as-mms-attachment)

just change set type with **image/png** or your image path.