# Android:How to send a voice as mms attachment?

Tags: java, android, mms

I have already done a voice recording by this code:

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                +"test.3gp");
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException io) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        recorder.start();
```

and trying to share it using a share intent like this:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        sharingIntent.setType("video/3gp");

            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, "file:///sdcard/Downloadtest.3gp");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

but when my mail is setup it send via email, but i want to share it vaia mms? its being attatched in mms? how to do it?

Comment: @NNirupoma Saha Chaiti accepted answer is work for you.you have to test in htc device.i have htc one can't attached file.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this in my case it work perfect.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
                sendIntent.putExtra("address", "9999999999");
                sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "if you are sending text");   
                final File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),"Downloadtest.3gp");
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file1);
                Log.e("Path", "" + uri);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                sendIntent.setType("video/3gp");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
```

But some device can't accept like Htc Desire,Htc one,lava.In Your case work perfect then paste code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code,

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
sendIntent.setType("audio/3gp");
```

Comment: I did the same u said, but not working :(

its saying 
sorry you can not add this picture in your message?

is there any specific file format?

Comment: @NirupomaSahaChaiti you have which device?because htc get error.